# Unable to connect to Access database with ADO

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado

I need to import a bunch of tables stored in .txt files into an Access database. When they are done importing, I use an ADO connection to communicate between the database and an Excel workbook. I have the Access database set to compact and repair on close.

The problem is, when I close the database after importing the files, I am unable to connect using ADO without waiting for an arbitrary amount of time. The Access window appears to be closed when I try to connect and fail. I have found that the amount of time I have to wait is related to the size of the database after import. After importing the largest sets of files, even a 60 second wait is not enough.

Is there some way I could force the connection to open? Of failing that, how could I check if it was ready to connect?

Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
MDB_Address = "C:\example.mdb" 
Shell "cmd /c " & Chr(34) & MDB_Address & Chr(34), vbHide
'Some code that tests if it has opened happens here
 ...

Set ObjAccess = GetObject("C:\example.mdb")

' Import tables here

ObjAccess.Quit

Call CloseAccess
Call Wait

mdbPath = "C:\example.mdb"
Set mdbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
' The line below gives a run time error. The description is "Automation error Unspecified Error"
mdbConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & mdbPath

Sub CloseAccess
' I have set up the access database to write a flag to a .txt file when a
   userform closes and use this to help check if it has closed.
End Sub

Sub Wait
' Wait 5 seconds. The access window appears to be closed.
Dim nHour As Date, nMinute As Date, nSecond As Date, waitTime As Date

nHour = Hour(Now())
nMinute = Minute(Now())
nSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
waitTime = TimeSerial(nHour, nMinute, nSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime
End Sub
```

Comment: Do example.mdb have user id & passwd ? If yes put them in connection string.

Comment: @Santosh, No they should not need a user ID and password. They key point is that I CAN connect to the mdb just fine using the code above, but ONLY after I have waited for an arbitrary amount of time (say 60 seconds) after the database closes.

Comment: @ In Call CloseAccess proc kindly make sure the instance of access is closed. set the ObjAccess = nothing. If its done properly then your database is ready for connection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Santosh. I think you are on to something when you say that I have to make sure the instance of Access is closed. However, setting the objAccess = Nothing did not help.

Comment: Edit: I thought it would be useful to point out that I am using the shell function to open access before I assign it to a variable with the GetObject Function. I am looking into using Windows API functions to test if it has closed.

Comment: Is there w reason why the files have to imported into Access, why not just import the text files directly into Excel?

Comment: @Philip, we designed this Workbook to work with an external Access database. There are advantages and disadvantages, but at this point I have to take that as a given.

Comment: I think your issue with delayed connection is due to the Compact and repair process happening in the background on close. Whilst this is happening, the db is still locked (isn't there an **.ldb** file or similar in the file directory to show it it's in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have ended up doing to test if the database is closed. I use Windows API functions to get the process handle for the Access database and then get its exit status.

This seems to work pretty well. There are surely other ways of accomplishing this - I think there is an ldb file that is created in the directory and it would probably work to check for its existence.

```
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long

'Open the data base
TaskID = Shell("cmd /c " & Chr(34) & MDB_Address & Chr(34), vbHide)
ACCESS_TYPE = &H400
hProc = OpenProcess(ACCESS_TYPE, False, TaskID)

'Some code that tests if it has opened happens here
 ...

Set ObjAccess = GetObject("C:\example.mdb")

' Import tables here

ObjAccess.Quit

Call CloseAccess

Sub CloseAccess()

    Dim test As Long

    'Test if the database has closed

    Do Until lExitCode <> 259 And test <> 0
        test = GetExitCodeProcess(hProc, lExitCode)
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```